# Parsing xml tree attributes (file has no elements)

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I have been trying to use minidom but have no real preference. For some reason lxml will not install on my machine.

I would like to parse an xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.
    -<transfer frmt="1" vtl="0" serial_number="E5XX-0822" date="2016-10-03 16:34:53.000" style="startstop">
        -<plateInfo>
              <plate barcode="E0122326" name="384plate" type="source"/>
              <plate barcode="A1234516" name="1536plateD" type="destination"/>
        </plateInfo>
        -<printmap total="1387">
            <w reason="" cf="13" aa="1.779" eo="299.798" tof="32.357" sv="1565.311" ct="1.627" ft="1.649" fc="88.226" memt="0.877" fldu="Percent" fld="DMSO" dy="0" dx="0" region="-1" tz="18989.481" gy="72468.649" gx="55070.768" avt="50" vt="50" vl="3.68" cvl="3.63" t="16:30:47.703" dc="0" dr="0" dn="A1" c="0" r="0" n="A1"/>
            <w reason="" cf="13" aa="1.779" eo="299.798" tof="32.357" sv="1565.311" ct="1.627" ft="1.649" fc="88.226" memt="0.877" fldu="Percent" fld="DMSO" dy="0" dx="0" region="-1" tz="18989.481" gy="72468.649" gx="55070.768" avt="50" vt="50" vl="3.68" cvl="3.63" t="16:30:47.703" dc="0" dr="0" dn="A1" c="1" r="0" n="A2"/>
        </printmap>
    </transfer>
```

The files do not have any element details, as you can see. All the information is contained in the attributes. In trying to adapt another SO post, I have this - but it seems to be geared more toward elements. I am also failing at a good way to "browse" the xml information, i.e. I would like to say "dir(xml_file)" and have a list of all the methods I can carry out on my tree structure, or see all the attributes. I know this was a lot and potentially different directions, but thank you in advance!

```
def parse(files):
    for xml_file in files:
        xmldoc = minidom.parse(xml_file)
        transfer = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('transfer')[0]
        plateInfo = transfer.getElementsByTagName('plateInfo')[0]
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using ElementTree -- ya know, [the one shipped in the Python standard library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)? `minidom` is one of the oldest out-of-the-box XML libraries, and it shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With minidom you can access the attributes of a particular element using the method attributes which can then be treated as dictionary; this example iterates and print the attributes of the element transfer[0]:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse, parseString
xml_file='''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <transfer frmt="1" vtl="0" serial_number="E5XX-0822" date="2016-10-03 16:34:53.000" style="startstop">
        <plateInfo>
              <plate barcode="E0122326" name="384plate" type="source"/>
              <plate barcode="A1234516" name="1536plateD" type="destination"/>
        </plateInfo>
        <printmap total="1387">
            <w reason="" cf="13" aa="1.779" eo="299.798" tof="32.357" sv="1565.311" ct="1.627" ft="1.649" fc="88.226" memt="0.877" fldu="Percent" fld="DMSO" dy="0" dx="0" region="-1" tz="18989.481" gy="72468.649" gx="55070.768" avt="50" vt="50" vl="3.68" cvl="3.63" t="16:30:47.703" dc="0" dr="0" dn="A1" c="0" r="0" n="A1"/>
            <w reason="" cf="13" aa="1.779" eo="299.798" tof="32.357" sv="1565.311" ct="1.627" ft="1.649" fc="88.226" memt="0.877" fldu="Percent" fld="DMSO" dy="0" dx="0" region="-1" tz="18989.481" gy="72468.649" gx="55070.768" avt="50" vt="50" vl="3.68" cvl="3.63" t="16:30:47.703" dc="0" dr="0" dn="A1" c="1" r="0" n="A2"/>
        </printmap>
    </transfer>'''
xmldoc = parseString(xml_file)
transfer = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('transfer')
attlist= transfer[0].attributes.keys()
for a in attlist:
    print transfer[0].attributes[a].name,transfer[0].attributes[a].value
```

you can find more information here:

http://www.diveintopython.net/xml_processing/attributes.html